# Statically resolved types with Records

Tags: generics, f#, type-parameter

You probably know the Adapter example below :

```
type Cat() =
member this.Walk() = printf "Cat walking"

type Dog() =
    member this.Walk() = printf "Dog walking"


let inline walk (animal : ^T ) =
    (^T : (member Walk : unit -> unit) (animal))

let cat = new Cat()
let dog = new Dog()

walk cat
walk dog
```

a different version of walk is compiled statically for the Cat and Dog classes.

Then I tried the following :

```
type Cat = { Name : string }
type Dog = { Name : string }

let inline showName (animal : ^T ) =
    let name = (^T : (member Name : string) (animal))
    printf "%s" name

let cat = { Name = "Miaou" } : Cat
let dog = { Name = "Waf" } : Dog

showName cat
showName dog
```

but I get the following compilation error :

```
The type 'Dog' does not support any operators named 'get_Name'
```

and the same for class Cat.

But when exploring the generated class for both records, it actually contains this get_Name method for the generated Name property.

Is there a different syntax to access Records fields in statically resolved generics, or is it a F# compiler limitation ?

Comment: I've run into this same issue with extension methods (should have known) and the static op_Append operator on F# lists. I'm curious as to this, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `showName` function implementation applies to standard .NET classes having `Name` property. Although neither `Cat` nor `Dog` are such; instead both are of **F# record** type.

Despite accessing a record `field` **looks literally similar** to accessing a standard class `property` for F# type inference these two cases are completely different.

You have defined two record types with non-unique field name `Name`; access to the field `Name` of instance `cat` of record type `Cat` is `cat.Name`, similarly for `dog` it is `dog.Name`. But when you try `showName cat` or `showName dog` compiler complains on absense of `Name` property in these record types, which is expected behavior, because there is no such property in these records.

**Addendum:**
To illustrate my point I did a slight modification to the original code adding property `Nickname` to both `Cat` and `Dog`:

```
type Cat = { Name : string } member x.Nickname = x.Name
type Dog = { Name : string } member x.Nickname = x.Name

let inline showName (animal : ^T ) =
    let name = (^T : (member Nickname : string) (animal))
    printfn "%s" name

let cat = { Name = "Miaou" } : Cat
let dog = { Name = "Waf" } : Dog

showName cat
showName dog
```

This will happily work.

Take a notice of signature of modified classes: it is now

```
type Cat =
  {Name: string;}
  with
    member Nickname : string
  end
```

And finally, the compiler will forbid having both a field and a property of a record type similarly named with `The member 'Xyzzy' can not be defined because the name 'Xyzzy' clashes with the field 'Xyzzy' in this type or module` message.

Comment: This is what I suspected, but since Records are compiled as standard .Net classes with fields compiled as Properties, I was expecting it to work. And its a bit sad that the member access syntax only works for .Net methods and properties (and not .Net fields, F# record fields etc)...

Comment: @RobertJeppesen: Sure it does **run** unchanged; check out `typeof<Cat>.GetProperty("Name").GetValue(cat, null)` will return `Miaou`, as you would expect from a regular property. But how does it help to reference a property not existing at **compile time**?

Answer (score 4):

It may be worth mentioning that record types can implement interfaces.

```
type INamedObject =
  abstract Name : string

type Cat = 
  { Name : string }
  interface INamedObject with
    member this.Name = this.Name

type Dog = 
  { Name : string }
  interface INamedObject with
    member this.Name = this.Name

let showName (namedObject : INamedObject) =
    printf "%s" namedObject.Name
```

You can also do

```
type Cat = { Name : string }
type Dog = { Name : string }

let showName (animal : obj) =
  let name =
    match animal with
    | :? Cat as cat -> cat.Name
    | :? Dog as dog -> dog.Name
    | _ -> invalidArg "animal" "Not an animal"
  printf "%s" name
```